# how to define different css for tab and mobile

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I am creating a web page and have to change some CSS in mobile and tab both, I have to define CSS for both, but only one of both is working, how to define different CSS for both devices.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>


<style type="text/css">

/*css for desktop*/ 
 .form-container{
    width: 60%;
    margin-left: 20%;
    margin-right: 20%;
    background: blue;

 }

 .form-container-inner{
    padding: 20px;
 }


/*css for tab*/

@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 1024px) {

  .form-container{
    width: 80%;
    margin-left: 10%;
    margin-right: 10%;
    background: red;

 }

}



/*css for mobile*/
 @media only screen and (max-width: 992px){

    .form-container{
    width: 100%;
    margin-left: 0%;
    margin-right: 0%;
    background: green;

 }
 }


</style>

<meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no" name="viewport">
</head>
<body>

<div class="form-container">
    <div class="form-container-inner">
    <label>Name</label>
    <input type="text" name="" >
    <br>

    <label>Surname</label>
    <input type="text" name="" >

    <br>

    <label>Password</label>
    <input type="text" name="" >
    </div>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You probably want to change the second media query to 767px

Answer (score 0):

You should set CSS style including all posibilities of screen:

```
/* On screens that are 768px or less */
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    // Your code
    .form-container{
        width: 100%;
        margin-left: 0%;
        margin-right: 0%;
        background: green;
    }
}
```

Other screens:

```
/* On screens that are between 768px and 1024px */
@media (min-width: 769px) and (max-width: 1024px) {
    // Your code
    .form-container{
        width: 80%;
        margin-left: 10%;
        margin-right: 10%;
        background: red;
    }
}
```

Edit: Thanks @ashfaq.p for the minor correction

Comment: it should be max-width: 767px

Answer (score 0):

```
/* CSS for tablets and above (768px and above) */

.form-container{
    width: 80%;
    margin-left: 10%;
    margin-right: 10%;
    background: red;
}

/* On screens that are 767px or less */

@media (max-width: 767px) {
  // Your code
  .form-container{
    width: 100%;
    margin-left: 0%;
    margin-right: 0%;
    background: green;
  }
}
```

And all the css for tab or above it should go as normal. They will be overriden by mobile media query

Answer (score 0):

As of my experience you don't need to define both `(min-width:*px)` and `(max-width: *px)`, you just need to define the entry point of the category.